# Is there a way to execute only code from a unit from a big exe placed on shared drive?

Tags: delphi, exe, delphi-10-seattle

I admit i am in the dirty tricks area in this question.

PROBLEM: exe is deployed on shared folder(I call it ShaExe from now on), without changing deployment rules somehow I want to cache the file locally (I call it LocExe fromnow on) and while launching ShaExe i finally end up running LocExe. LocExe must be updated (copied from ShaExe) everytime ShaExe is modified (=updated).

Somehow what I am researching is setting up something like this:

Prerequisite: LocExe path is an user\AppData\Local\MyApp harcoded path so ShaExe knows where LocExe is.

1. ShaExe is launched
2. ShaExe compares its size with the size of LocExe, if different it copies ShaExe over LocExe
3. ShaExe executes LocExe with the `-skiplauncher` command line parameter
4. ShaExe terminates itself

when `-skiplauncher` is used points 2 3 4 of the above list are not executed (this is to avoid an endless loop of executing LocExe and terminating the applcation)

Now this approach works, but the bottleneck is (1) because ShaExe size is 110MB so somehow launching an exe from shared path takes time (Even if I do not use the flag `{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}`).

I tried to prepare a very small version of ShaExe (basically built without units but only with the launcher logic in it ending up in 6MB of exe).

WIth this "light but useless ShaExe" the whole process is faster.

I would like that (2) (3) and (4) are executed immediately, is this possible or not with Windows?

I am perfectly aware the best practice would be either to copy manually the file locally and run it or create a simple launcher exe that does the job of running LocExe doing the cache when necessary, but I have a very big customer that requires me to do this without changing the deployment procedure.

THis is why I ask for expert advice here.

This is my code (of course simplified, instead of Unit1 imagine 100 units):

```
//this is the dpr
program MYProgram;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  execache in 'execache.pas',
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  RunCachedExe;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.

//this is the execache unit
unit execache;

interface

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Windows,
  ShellAPi,
  sysutils,
  dialogs,
  system.IOUtils;

  procedure RunCachedExe;

implementation

procedure RunCachedExe;

function GetFileSize(const aFilename: String): Int64;
  var
    info: TWin32FileAttributeData;
  begin
    result := -1;
    if NOT GetFileAttributesEx(PWideChar(aFileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @info) then
      EXIT;
    result := Int64(info.nFileSizeLow) or Int64(info.nFileSizeHigh shl 32);
  end;

var
  CurrentInstanceSize, CachedFileSize, i: integer;
  CachedFilePath, Outs: string;
  SkipLauncher: Boolean;
begin
  SkipLauncher := False;
  for i := 0 to paramcount -1 do
    begin
      if Paramstr(i) = '-SkipLauncher' then
        SkipLauncher := True;
    end;
  if not SkipLauncher then
  begin
    // in this code path is hardcoded, in real life I use a function that calls:
    // SHGetSpecialFolderPath with CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA
     CachedFilePath := 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\MyProject\bincache\MyProject.exe';
     CurrentInstanceSize := GetFileSize(Application.ExeName);
     // this will return -1 if file not found
     CachedFileSize := GetFileSize (CachedFilePath);
     if CachedFileSize <> CurrentInstanceSize then
     begin
       ForceDirectories('C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\MyProject\bincache\');
       CopyFile(PChar(Application.ExeName), PCHar(CachedFilePath), False);
     end;
     // launch local exe and close this one
     ShellExecute (0, 'open', PWideChar( CachedFilePath ), PWideChar('-SkipLauncher'), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
     Application.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

This code uses some functions from other units but I could move all in the execache unit, if this could help to speed up the execution of the exe.

Somehow I would like to run only an initialization part, containing the logic described here and then terminate the app (when ShaExe is in place, that basically means when `-skipLauncher` is not used).

So, is it possible to run only an initialization logic of a big exe file?

I hope I expressed myself, thanks.

Comment: Don't let your customer push you this way. All that will happen is that you will end up with an even bigger mess than you already have.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for your comment. I totally agree on this with you but in my case i am just a gear in a complex machine and I execute orders. Of course I can say what I think and influence decisions, but anyway is there a way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean, for sure you can create programs that copy files around and launch processes. Very hard to see what the question actually is. You clearly know how to copy files. You clearly know how to launch processes (although you are doing it wrong, it should be `CreateProcess` that you call). So I've no idea what your question is, and I am sure that all you will succeed in achieving here is that your customers experience will be degraded.

Comment: Presumably you've considered the possibility of wrapping the functionality of Loc.Exe in a locally-deployed Dll?  What would be your client's objection to that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my question is about the feasibilty of making a 100+ MB exe deployed on a shaerd folder behave as it iwere a 5 MB exe by running only an initializiation routine. I am aware this is a odd idea and all this work should be done by an IT admin. I see what I look for is not doable (because of how exe work in Windows, at least I think it is not possible considering by reading your comments). i will try not to implement this solution.

Comment: You seem to be confused. The executable on the remote location will be loaded to the memory space of the local machine. Even if the first instruction is Halt the entire runtime will be fetched. It doesn't matter if it is possible to run only initialization logic - why shouldn't it be possible? You should be chasing the other way around: a local copy should be checking to see if a remote location hosts an updated version...

Comment: @MartynA honestly I did not consider the dll solution but it would not solve my problem of auto updating executable file because it would introduce a new player (the dll) in the game. Thanks.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes somehow your comment answers my question. It is a possible solution but of course one should create at least once a copy of the file and then the process coudl work. If you post as answer i can accept it.

Comment: If executing the file on a network share takes time then the problem is the performance of the network. You are letting your customer take technical decisions when they don't understand the issues. This is just a giant waste of time for everybody. Surely it's best to solve the problem properly.

Comment: What is the problem of having a launcher application that creates a local copy of the actual application? Why would that change anything for the customer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the code you have, what you are essentially asking is if partially loading an executable is possible, to have it conditionally execute only a portion of the code it contains. Or a streaming executable perhaps? These are not possible, the OS will have to fetch the entire runtime from the remote location, together with any static dependencies, to the local computer. Even if the executable is to exit immediately.

You can have the behavior you want by separating the conditional part to a different executable though: a launcher. Without any VCL dependency you can have it really small. Even then, the better alternative is to run the executable locally to have it check if a remote location contains an updated version, since networked access is more prone to performance and security issues.

Comment: Thanks, the fact the OS needs to fetch the entire runtime is something i was suspecting from tests, but i was not sure. Now i know what i was trying to achieve is not possible so iwill look for another solution.

Comment: Is that really true. Surely the system just needs to map the executable. It only fetches it when there are page misses.

Comment: @David, that is what I mean by fetching, file contents are carried over the network to be able to be loaded onto the memory of the local computer. I don't mean the files are copied or etc..

Comment: But surely the contents are only fetched when paged in

Comment: @David I don't know when paging occurs, contents are fetched before the executable is started.

Comment: @LaB Does your application require you to confirm any kind of security warning before it runs? Elevation consent...  Do you want to run this file.. etc..

Comment: I'm not as sure as I was before I wrote this post now, @David may be in fact right and this may not be the de facto behavior. I was trying to come up with some easy setup to prove when I realized it was different with regular applications.

Comment: Certainly on a local drive the file contents are mapped and then paged on demand. I'd expect the same for a network volume. Exactly how that performs could depend on the volume.

Comment: @David - However, on a local drive any component that renders the design useless might quite easily go unnoticed. It's very easy to verify, launch "process monitor", launch any application that would ask for elevation consent on a share, and then watch consent.exe read the entire file. No mapping or anything, just through ReadFile, entire contents... Explorer.exe reads the entire file in the case of a security dialog. Maybe it's the same locally, I didn't event test that.